# Automatic commit of an approved diff in Review Board

Tags: svn, review-board

When I approve a review request in Review Board, can it be configured in such a fashion that it commits the diff file to the SVN automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by shipping review request, do you send it by e-mail? What does 'automatically' mean, do you want to use some kind of continuous integration? And what solution do you expect? It is really difficult to provide an answer for your question without getting more information on the matter.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible in the current release of Review Board.

The repository may have been committed to since the time of the review posting, and this means applying of the diff might fail. Since reviews usually take some time, I suppose this feature would not be feasible in general use, barring marginal cases of rarely updated source.

Review Board 2.0 [is expected to support extensions](http://code.google.com/p/reviewboard/wiki/IdeasFor2_0), and IMHO this looks like a job for extensions rather than a core feature.