# Does Review Board support automatic code commit into SVN after shipping the review request in "pre-commit review" mode

Tags: svn, review-board

Now my team is trying to add code review practices into development process, and I have deployed [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/).

Below is a typical scenario:

1. **Developer**: Revise some code files.
2. **Developer**: Create a patch file by TortoiseSVN
3. **Developer**: Create a review request in Review Board, upload the patch file and assign the request to some reviewers.
4. **Reviewer**: Log on to Review Board and review the code diff (During this period, there may be some issues reported by reviewers.)
5. **Developer**: Fixed the issues
6. **Reviewer**: Ship the review request.
7. **Developer**: Close the review request as "Submitted".
8. **Developer**: Commit the code into SVN by TortoiseSVN.

My question is:

Is it possible that when developer close the review request in Step 7, the code will be committed into SVN automatically at the same time, rather than using TortoiseSVN to commit in step 8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic commit of an approved diff in Review Board](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310625/automatic-commit-of-an-approved-diff-in-review-board)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, there is no such option. But then you can come up with a pre-commit hook script which will automatically create the review board request based on the description provided. But then this will always slow down the commit process. And integrating review board with SVN commit operation is not a good idea since the reviews takes time usually.